# pandas assume integer type data and would not allow set text

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I can't set a new value in a pandas data frame except if it is an integer.

I am learning pandas and trying to build as many cases as possible playing with .loc and .iloc in a jupyter notebook and I encounter the first problem that i don't understand. I can set a particular value of the pandas data frame to a new value with .loc as long as it is an integer. otherwise error why?

```
onp=np.arange(1,21,1).reshape(4,5)
oindex=['concept1','concept2','concept3','concept4',]
ohead=['ep1','ep2','ep3','ep5','ep5']
data=onp

mydf=pd.DataFrame(data,index=oindex, columns=ohead)
print(mydf.loc['concept2','ep3'])

# this works fine:
mydf.loc['concept2','ep3']=233

# this does not work:
mydf.loc['concept2','ep3']='hallo'
```

why does python assume that the values of the data frame are integers?
what do I have to do to change the values to a kind of variant. I would need to have text or integers in randomly distributed places of the pandas.
thanks

btw, the error through is:
"ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will allow once you change the datatype to `object`

```
mydf=mydf.astype(object)
mydf.loc['concept2','ep3']='hallo' 
mydf
Out[181]: 
         ep1 ep2    ep3 ep5 ep5
concept1   1   2      3   4   5
concept2   6   7  hallo   9  10
concept3  11  12     13  14  15
concept4  16  17     18  19  20
```

Comment: thanks. it works. will mark in answer in two minutes.

Comment: @JoseBerlines yw :-) happy coding,  also do not forget upvote :-)